# Javascript Date.now() function returning null

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have the following segment of code:

```
//Main game loop
var main = function () {

    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now - then;
    update(delta / 1000);
    render();
    then = now;
    //Request to perform again
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
};
```

and while debugging I came across a pretty strange error.
It's returning the **then** variable, but returning null for the **now** variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Been scratching my head at this for a while!
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: When did you check the value of `now`? If you did after the function, then thats the problem. `now` is a local(ly initialized) variable.

Comment: @Felk Submit as an answer, it worked. You deserve your points. Simple simple solution lol.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `new Date()` instead. It will instantiate it to the current time.

Comment: Just did that, now it's returning the full date when instead I need a timestamp. And still returns null for the **now** variable, and the date for the **then** variable.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP wants the milliseconds, not the Date object. `Date.now()` is the right tool for that already.

Answer (score 0):

`Date.now()` works just fine (Don't think of using `Date.parse(new Date())`). Define and initialize `then` before it's first use. What is the value of `then` in `now - then`?

Here are some facts:

1. The variable `now` is local to the function and therefore is unknown outside of the function.
2. The function does not return any value and can therefore not pass the value of `now` to calling scope.
3. Nowhere in your code do you call the function. The function is just defined; it has to be call to execute the code within it.

```js
var now = Date.now();

alert( now );
```